# Metricbeat to many modules enabled by default

Tags: jolokia, metricbeat

I am experimenting with **Metricbeat using Docker-Compose** but I am **only interested in get metric via Jolokia at the start**.

At the moment is starting with all the modules enabled by default and this generates a huge **schema in Elastic with more than 2000** fields up front.

Is there a why to **enable just specific modules to start** with when using the Docker image installation.

Thank you, kindly
   Luis Oscar Trigueiros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really possible right now; it enables the dynamic enabling and disabling of modules without having to alter any mappings. Since index templates are only applied at index creation it would otherwise be much trickier to add the right fields with explicit statements later on.

But is this an issue in the first place? Or what would you be trying to fix?

Comment: It is not a big problem, but I find it confusing to when viewing the and  querying using Kibana, because I am using Metricbeat only with JMX/Jolokia metrics having all other fields in the schema is confusing, and maybe this is just a totally newbie question or problem.

Comment: True, that is a bit of an inconvenience. I'm wondering if we can change that — there will be some new things around central management of configs. Let's see...